# MYSQL will not return more than 1 category

Tags: php, mysql

I've tried to find an answer to this problem, but I can't.

I have a 3 table format mqsql database. 
I use 1 table to add all of the product information, CarpetInfo, 
1 Table to list my categories, CarpetCategories, 
and 1 Table to add categories to the products, CarpetCategorySort.

My CarpetCategorySort table has 3 columns, Manufacturer, Style, CategoryID.
Example would be Manufacturer = Aladdin, Style = Alma Mater, CategoryID = 14/ 15/ 18/ 19/ 20/ 21/ 67/

My CarpetCategories Table has 2 Columns CategoryID and Category.
2 Examples would be CategoryID = 14, Category = Commercial & 
CategoryID = 15, Category = Commercial Loop

I can only get the code to work when I type in Commercial into the $category variable below. The code will not work if I type Commercial Loop into the $category variable. It's like it will only pull in the first number 14 and all of the others are ignored. The pricing order and everything else works right, just not the CategoryID part.

Here is my code.

```
<?php $mill = "Aladdin"; $category = "Commercial Loop";
$order = mysqli_query($con, "
SELECT * FROM CarpetInfo JOIN CarpetCategorySort USING (Manufacturer, Style) 
JOIN CarpetCategories USING (CategoryID)
WHERE Manufacturer='$mill' AND Category LIKE '%$category%'
order by Price = 0, Price asc,
Style asc");
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/pricing/carpet-order-test.htm');?>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: It's a good idea to space that out a bit better. Jamming things on one line severely impairs readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a backward way of handling things, a field with several datapoints smooshed together like that really never has any justification for existence.  I'd list the carpets in one table, list the categories in another, and finally list cross-references of both in another table, where you get a many-to-one relationship at both ends.

You need an actual category table only if you think it's going to take so much room to give duplicate info for each category and/or you can't control user input for categories (like you aren't just using a pulldown to give a name choice).

Something like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `carpets` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `abbrev` varchar(10),
  `description` varchar(250),
  [...]
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `carpet_categories` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `carpet_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
[...]
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `carpet_category_info` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `price-per-sqf` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50),
   [...]
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

then all your joins become simple, and fast..  And accurate.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you this would be a better way to go. Sorry I've only been in mysql for a few months now. Can you give me a little more info about the reasoning behind your tables/code?

Comment: @k1775 you don't have a field which lists several instance of one thing all mashed together - you have a separate table which contains several records, each of which associates a different thing with the original record. The former structure is more.. Excel than relational database.  you might want to read up on the general principles involved? https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/sql/relational_database_design.html or any o'reilly sql book